# to compare the data between 2 table with no common column

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables.My first table is having only column(i.e. DATE) with single row data and
Second table having 3 column ( cost ,startdate ,enddate)with multiple rows of data.I need to get table2.cost value only if table1.date exist between table2.startdate and table2.enddate Intervel.

can anyone please tell me query for above scenario with respect to sql

Comment: Select cost from secondtable where startdate <= (select date from firsttable) and enddate >= (select date from firsttable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get records from the second table once for each matching date, you can join the tables:

```
select
  t2.cost
from
  Table2 t2
  inner join Table1 t1 on t1.theDate >= t2.startdate and t1.theDate < t2.enddate
```

To get matching records from the second table only once even when more than one date matches from the first table, you can use `exists`:

```
select
  t2.cost
from
  Table2 t2
where
  exists (
    select *
    from Table1 t1
    where t1.theDate >= t2.startdate and t1.theDate < t2.enddate
  )
```

Note: I have used the `>=` and `<` operators in the comparisons assuming that the `startdate` is inclusive and the `enddate` is exclusive. If the `enddate` is inclusive you can use the `<=` operator instead of `<`, or use the `between` operator.